# Installing SDL in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, sdl-2

I have Cygwin, setup version 2.8473, 64-bit.  I've installed gcc-g++.  I am trying to install SDL2, trying both SDL2-2.0.3 and SDL2-2.0.4.  I'll talk about the problems with 2.0.3, since that's the stable release.

I [read](http://www.noquarterarcade.com/using-cygwin-for-sdl-development) that I should run /usr/bin/set-gcc-default-3.sh, but it's not there.  (gcc does seem to have been installed, as I see it working when I run make in the SDL2-2.0.3 directory.)  I haven't been able to find out where to get it by searching Internet -- maybe this is it?  Without it, `make` gives me these complaints:

```
Warning, configure.in is out of date
```

and lots of "static declaration" errors like this:

```
.../SDL_render_d3d11.c:135:19: error: static declaration of 'IID_IDXGIFactory2' follows non-static declaration
   static const GUID IID_IDXGIFactory2 = { 0x50c83a1c, 0xe072, 0x4c48, { 0x87, 0xb
               ^
```

I wasn't able to find anything useful googling `IID_IDXGIFactory2`.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't run `configure`

Comment: No, I did.  Not at all sure why it's saying that.  I'm going to delete the directory and ./configure again.

Comment: I got the same error now... no clue.

Comment: You can't use the sdl package available in the cygwin installer?

Comment: I can't find any reference to an sdl package in the cygwin installer, or on Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the SDL Wiki's page on [installation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation), "As of SDL 2.0.3, the codebase still compiles on Cygwin and MingW32, but we expect these to stop working in the future."  So it's no longer supported, and I'll leave it.

Comment: This is to bad. I think cyqwin is a great tool and it would be a shame to see it atrophy...